# mmenu and google publisher tags are compatiable?

Tags: google-dfp, mmenu

mmenu crashes the page when used with Google Publisher Tags (async), as soon as the page loads the css formatting and html structure seems to be lost and all further javascript execution stops. It can be reproduced by adding a google publisher tag in the demo file of mmenu download.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
<script type='text/javascript'>
(function() {
var useSSL = 'https:' == document.location.protocol;
var src = (useSSL ? 'https:' : 'http:') +
'//www.googletagservices.com/tag/js/gpt.js';
document.write('<scr' + 'ipt src="' + src + '"></scr' + 'ipt>');
})();
</script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
googletag.defineSlot('/5910/symall/ROS', [1, 1], 'div-gpt-ad-1403693262284-0').addService(googletag.pubads());
googletag.pubads().enableSyncRendering();
googletag.pubads().enableSingleRequest();
googletag.pubads().collapseEmptyDivs(); 
googletag.enableServices();
</script>


        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="author" content="www.frebsite.nl" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width initial-scale=1.0 maximum-scale=1.0 user-scalable=yes" />

        <title>jQuery.mmenu demo</title>

        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/demo.css" />
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="../src/css/jquery.mmenu.css" />

        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../src/js/jquery.mmenu.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">

        $.fn.mmenu.debug = function( msg ) {
   console.log( msg );
};
            $(function() {
                $('nav#menu').mmenu();
            });

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="page">
            <div class="header">
                <a href="#menu"></a>
                Demo
            </div>
            <div class="content">
                <p><strong>This is a demo.</strong><br />
                    Click the menu icon to open the menu.</p>
                <p>For more demos, a tutorial, documentation and support, please visit <a href="http://mmenu.frebsite.nl" target="_blank">mmenu.frebsite.nl</a></p>
            </div>
            <nav id="menu">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#about">About us</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#about/history">History</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#about/team">The team</a>
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="#about/team/management">Management</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#about/team/sales">Sales</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#about/team/development">Development</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#about/address">Our address</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>

                <!-- SYMALL/ROS -->
        <div id='div-gpt-ad-1403693262284-0'>
        <script type='text/javascript'>
                        googletag.display('div-gpt-ad-1403693262284-0');
        </script>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: And what is your question? What have you tried and hasn't worked?

Comment: no it doesnt work, but ive been able to pin down the problem to `googletag.pubads().enableSyncRendering();` when i comment this out, the page loads fine.

Comment: Hi great, that helps. The more information about the problem you give the more likely you are to get a timely answer. Also showing that you've actually tried solving the problem will convince many people to take the time to help you ;) Just some SO beginner tips. Wish I knew how to help you...

Comment: Be sure to check out: https://github.com/BeSite/jQuery.mmenu/issues/90